# Error "Undeclared Variable" occur when try to use isset() two times in a document

Tags: php, html

To fetch a name from database randomly

index.php

```
<?php
//Database initialization
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "APB", "12345678", "apb");
if (isset($_POST["button1"])) {
    $number = mt_rand(1, 10);


    $s   = "SELECT * FROM student_list WHERE NUM='$number'";
    $r   = mysqli_query($connection, $s);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);


    $StudName  = $row["NAME"];
    $studClass = $row["CLASS"];

}
if (isset($_POST["b1"])) {
    $number = mt_rand(1, 10);


    $s   = "SELECT * FROM choose WHERE sl='$number'";
    $r   = mysqli_query($connection, $s);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

    $Name = $row["item"];

    $StudName = "";
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form" action="" name="form1" method="POST">
        <table width="1057" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div align="left">MPTC FRESHER'S DAY CELEBRATION - 2017 </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>This time the lucky one is ...</p>

        <p>

            <input name="button1" type="submit" id="button1" value="GENERATE" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="t1" name="textfield" type="text" value="<?php echo $StudName?>" size="35" maxlength="30" />

            </div>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <div>Choose One ..... </div>
            <div>
                <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="b1" value="1" />
                <input id="b2" type="submit" name="Submit2" value="2" />
                <input id="b3" type="submit" name="Submit3" value="3" />
                <input id="b4" type="submit" name="Submit4" value="4" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input name="textfield2" value="<?php echo $Name?>" type="text" size="30" />
            </div>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit5" value="COMPUTER" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input name="textfield3" type="text" size="60" />
            </div>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

> Error "Notice:  Undefined variable: Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\FDAY\index.php 
>   on line 80"

When I tried to write the code for both buttons button1 and b1, it shows error.

Comment: `$_POST["b1"]` is not set, so `$Name` is never defined. Assuming you want to use the same code and simply display the variable **if** it's set, set `$Name` to `''` **outside** of the condition.

Comment: With the same code button1 alone work properly, but when add code for b1 ,the other button, it shows error.

Comment: Got it, I used the button id instead of button name. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
<div>
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="b1"  value="1" />
  ...
</div>
```

To this

```
<div>
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="b1" name="b1"  value="1" />
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You, It was my mistake :)

Comment: As it worked, please accept the answer @ArchanaP.Babu

Comment: Ok, but i have already identified the fault and mentioned here before you provide the Answer. See the comments above